# Display error message in view with rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this `rescue_from` line in my controller

```
rescue_from StandardError, with: :shipping_error
```

This is the `create` action in my controller

```
def create
  shop = ShippingMethod.create(shipping_method_params)
  assigned_shop = assign_shipping_variables(shop)
  if assigned_shop.valid?
    redirect_to edit_shipping_method_path(assigned_shop)
  else
   shipping_error
  end
end
```

And this is `shipping_error` a private method in the same controller

```
def shipping_error
  @error = "Hey don't touch me there"
  render :back
end
```

In my model I validate for `numericality`

Finally , I have a form in a partial called `_tab` and I just want to display `@error` when the validation fails.. I can't seem to get it there..

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you still need an answer for that?

Comment: Nope, all good. thanks